# Compiling for x64 on x86 System in VS08, no binaries are created

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction, 64-bit

I've got a C++ (Native) DLL that I'm trying to compile for x64 on my x86 system, which should work fine, but the actual binaries are not being created.  The build process runs and VS says that everything was successful, but when I go into .\x64\Release\ the only file that is there is test.dll.intermediate.manifest, which is just a bunch of xml code.

Any idea why this would be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can they be created in some other location?

Try to increase build output verbosity by changing Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/Build and Run/"MSBuild project build output verbosity" setting to Detailed, hopefully that would allow you to see where the binaries are created.

Comment: I doubt it...I searched my entire hard drive for the file... but I'll give this a shot and get back.

Comment: Didn't really show anything different..., shows this "LINK : .\Debug/test.dll not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link" but the file is never really linked

Comment: Have you checked build log file? There should be an output message with a link to the build log file, something like 1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\olegtk\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Foo\Foo\Debug\BuildLog.htm" That file should contain details about parameters passed to the compiler, in particular /OUT parameter with full path to output file name.

Comment: You were right... they were being created in the Win32 directories, which is why I didn't notice, since they look the same.  The Linker settings and been inherited from the original Win32 settings and never got changed... thanks!